# How do I refer to the current line/observation number in a loop in the data step?

Tags: sas

For example, I have data on various latencies that I iterate through and apply a linear function to, as shown: (the function is just an example here)

```
data latency;
input lat1 - lat20;
array cost[20];
array lat[20];
do x = 1 to 20;
cost[x] = lat[x] * 1.875;
end;
drop x;
datalines;
0.42 0.85 0.59 0.06 0.21 0.35 0.1 0.08 0.85 0.53 0.81 0.44 0.47 0.2 0.99 0.32 0.18 0.87 0.33 0.84
0.11 0.83 0.02 0.59 0.74 0.65 0.76 0.45 0.57 0.22 0.2 0.13 0.42 0.15 0.05 0.51 0.48 0.95 0.39 0.92
0.8 0.9 0.65 0.29 0.77 0.0 0.24 0.05 0.16 0.72 0.58 0.9 0.35 0.63 0.79 0.41 0.73 0.36 0.82 0.16
0.74 0.21 0.57 0.73 0.83 0.78 0.77 0.92 0.13 0.39 0.52 0.14 0.1 0.77 0.68 0.99 0.26 0.37 0.97 0.83
;
run;
```

How can I save a variable with the current observation number in each iteration of the loop, so that I can use it in calculations later?

I know that `proc print` will automatically print the observation number, but how do I access this and store it to a variable in the data step? Is there a way to do this as sas reads the datalines line by line?

I tried this, but then the `obs` variable is 2 for every observation.

```
data latency;
input lat1 - lat20;
obs = 1;                 * ADDED LINE;
array cost[20];
array lat[20];
do x = 1 to 20;
cost[x] = lat[x] * 1.875;
end;
obs = obs + 1;           * ADDED LINE;
drop x;
datalines;
0.42 0.85 0.59 0.06 0.21 0.35 0.1 0.08 0.85 0.53 0.81 0.44 0.47 0.2 0.99 0.32 0.18 0.87 0.33 0.84
0.11 0.83 0.02 0.59 0.74 0.65 0.76 0.45 0.57 0.22 0.2 0.13 0.42 0.15 0.05 0.51 0.48 0.95 0.39 0.92
0.8 0.9 0.65 0.29 0.77 0.0 0.24 0.05 0.16 0.72 0.58 0.9 0.35 0.63 0.79 0.41 0.73 0.36 0.82 0.16
0.74 0.21 0.57 0.73 0.83 0.78 0.77 0.92 0.13 0.39 0.52 0.14 0.1 0.77 0.68 0.99 0.26 0.37 0.97 0.83
;
run;

proc print data=latency;
run;
```

This is a small example, but in reality I can't simply add a new variable that stores the line number to the start of each data line and read it in. That isn't practical for the actual data set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add a `retain` statement so SAS doesn't reset `obs` to 0 at every new observation.

```
data latency;
retain obs 0;
obs = obs + 1;
...
run;
```

Comment: Alternately, do this:  `data latency; obs+1;`  Writing it without the equals makes it automatically retained.

Comment: @Joe If I add `obs = obs + 1` inside the loop, however, it only takes on the values 20, 40, 60, 80, etc. Shouldn't the `retain` statement increment once for every variable and for every data line, if it's inside the loop?

Comment: If you put it in the loop and don't output it, you don't get the 20 different values.  RETAIN doesn't have anything to do with incrementing - it just says don't clear the value out when you hit the end of data step loop.  In your case you need an OUTPUT, if you want one row per value instead of 20 values per row.  I think you aren't sufficiently clear with what you want - both answers you received answer the question slightly differently from how I read it, but I can't figure out exactly what you want.  Try fleshing it out, maybe give an example of what it would look like if it were correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your first attempt was very close.  Try again, but this time replace this line:

```
obs = 1;                 * ADDED LINE;
```

With this:

```
retain obs 0;            * ADDED LINE;
```

That way, your `obs` variable will be retained across your entire dataset instead of being reset to 1 each time.